# Change the logo in Gentelella template

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, gentelella

I'm currently experimenting the Gentelella template with RoR and it's fantastic ! But I just have one problem that I cannot fix for the moment, it's making the logo responsive.

Because actually, I can define it just once. So I have to choose between sm/md `sidenav` for my image dimension.

So do you know any solution (like a condition) to display a different image if the sidebar is open or close

Comment: Post your code here